# Pass name created in Name Manager Excel to Function VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created a name in Name Manager. How to pass the name "MyRange1" parameter for my function in VBA code?

In Excel:

```
=MyFunction(MyRange1)
```

MyFunction is:

```
Public Function MyFunction(nameDefined As Variant) As String
    'How get value of nameDefined ??
End Function
```

Comment: `Range("MyRange1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't pass `Range("MyRange1")` in my function `=MyFunction(Range("MyRange1"))` not work.

Comment: =MyFunction(MyRange1)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, How to get the value of myRange1 in MyFunction ?

Comment: You pass the name as string (so variant is okay). In the body of that function you use `Range()`  to convert the passed string to a range.

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** ways to pass a Named Range:

1. as a `String`
2. as a `Range` Object

so a *UDF()* in a worksheet cell would have either:

```
=myudf("Name1")
```

or

```
=myudf(Name1)
```

Naturally, the UDF() would have to be coded to expect one or the other,

Note that there could be volatility problems with using only a `String`.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an example of passing a `Range` rather than a `String`.  Say we create `MyRange1` like:

[image]

and the *UDF()* is like:

```
Public Function MyFunction(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        MyFunction = MyFunction & "..." & r.Text
    Next r
End Function
```

Then we can use it in a worksheet cell like:

```
=MyFunction(MyRange1)
```

[image]

Once the *UDF()* has the range, it can get the list of items contained therein.

Comment: "Naturally, the UDF() would have to be coded to expect one or the other"  or perhaps both (with appropriate use of `TypeName` on the passed argument).

Comment: It works, but if `myRange1` is a srtring list? how to proceed?

Comment: @Ragnar you need to first figure out what your question is. Exactly what is your function trying to accomplish? You're passing in a `Variant`, which could be anything from a `String` to a `Long` to a `Range` of cells or anything else that's possible to pass to a function from an Excel formula. Your question is unclear as long as we don't know what you're trying to do. You can't get "the value" of a "string list", that makes no sense.

Comment: @Ragnar  See my **EDIT#1**    Does this help ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Yes. It possible put strings in `Refers To` like this `= { "Str1"; "Srt2" }`?

Answer (score 0):

To figure out similar questions, you can put a Breakpoint in the code and analyse the Locals window:

[image]

From the Locals window you can notice that you can access "Str2" with `nameDefined(2,1)`
( or in your version of Excel it might be `nameDefined(2)` for horizontal array )

You can also check the run-time type with some of the VBA functions:

```
t = VBA.TypeName(nameDefined) ' t = "Variant()"
v = VBA.VarType(nameDefined)  ' v = vbArray + vbVariant ( = 8204 )
b = VBA.IsArray(nameDefined)  ' b = True ( also True for range with more than one cell )
```